# “Giusto” nel senso di “soltanto”?

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs

Mi sono accorto solo da poco che l'uso avverbiale di “giusto” nel senso di “soltanto” («Mi fermo giusto due minuti») è assente o appena accennato dai dizionari. Mi chiedo quindi: è un calco dall'inglese *just* oppure è attestato in “buon” italiano, per esempio in scrittori più o meno classici?

Comment: Grazie, @randomatlabuser, ma è un uso un po' diverso da quello a cui mi riferivo. Qui “giusto” equivale a “proprio, per l'appunto”, e non al “soltanto” a cui mi riferivo. Nel [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giusto1/) la tua è l'accezione 4.b, esemplificata con «l’ho incontrato g. ora; sei arrivato g. in tempo; cercavo g. te», mentre il senso di “soltanto” non è contemplato.

Comment: @randomatlabuser *Amplissimo*, per favore. `;-)`

Comment: @randomatlabuser Quando la legge imporrà *ampissimo* smetterò di parlare italiano. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

Secondo me, probabilmente è l'inglese "just" (dal latino "iūstus") ad aver ereditato i suoi vari significati dalle lingue neolatine, forse dal francese?

Non sono convinto che in italiano "giusto" sia usato nel senso di "soltanto" quanto piuttosto di "esattamente", "precisamente", "non più di", "appena", "proprio". Come osserva DaG, la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giusto1/) al punto 4 ne considera gli usi avverbiali. Non vedo differenze sostanziali tra "giusto due minuti" e, per esempio, "giusto un po'" come in [Vassallo (ligure, 1924)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/v/vassallo/guerra_in_tempo_di_bagni_racconto/pdf/guerra_p.pdf), "giusto appena" come in [Anna Vertua Gentile (lombarda, 1922)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/v/vertua/carlo_e_carla/pdf/carlo__p.pdf) o "giusto un momento" come in [Guerrazzi (toscano, 1864)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/g/guerrazzi/paolo_pelliccioni/pdf/guerrazzi_paolo_pelliccioni.pdf).

Per fare qualche altro esempio, anche se DaG li considera fuori tema, "giusto in quel momento" è usato da [Verga (siciliano, 1883)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/v/verga/tutte_le_novelle/html/coseilre.htm), [De Amicis (piemontese, primi anni del 1900)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/d/de_amicis/primo_maggio/pdf/primo__p.pdf), [Capuana (siciliano, 1898)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/c/capuana/scurpiddu/pdf/scurpi_p.pdf), [Deledda (sarda, 1911)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/d/deledda/sino_al_confine/pdf/deledda_sino_al_confine.pdf), [De Roberto (campano, 1889)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/d/de_roberto/processi_verbali/pdf/proces_p.pdf), [Svevo (friulano, 1898)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/s/svevo/senilita/pdf/svevo_senilita.pdf), [Serao (campana, 1890)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/s/serao/il_paese_di_cuccagna/pdf/il_pae_p.pdf), [Bertelli (toscano, 1907)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/bertelli/il_giornalino_di_gian_burrasca/pdf/il_gio_p.pdf), [Castelnuovo (toscano, 1899)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/c/castelnuovo/i_coniugi_varedo/pdf/castelnuovo_i_coniugi_varedo.pdf), [Baffo (veneziano, 1789)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/baffo/raccolta_universale_2/pdf/baffo_raccolta_universale_2.pdf), [Pirandello (siciliano, 1903)](http://www.classicitaliani.it/pirandel/novelle/novelle_16_Appendice.htm). "Giusto allora" in [Berneri (romano, 1695)](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/berneri/il_meo_patacca_ovvero_roma_etc/pdf/il_meo_p.pdf).

Spulciando tra gli autori meridionali si trova che "giusto" in senso avverbiale è molto diffuso (solo al link di Pirandello ne compaiono una decina di occorrenze!). Esempi spettacolari al link di Berneri (Meo Patacca), alcuni potrebbero essere proprio quelli ricercati dal DaG.

NB: Provvedo a cancellare i miei commenti sopra, raccolti in questa risposta, per evitare di fare confusione.

Answer (score 0):

"giusto cinque minuti" è un'espressione colloquiale molto diffusa. Nella lingua scritta "canonica" non è utilizzato. Lo si trova in scritti di taglio più "nazionale-popolare" .

Comment: errata corrige: "nazional-popolare" !!!